# Python check divisibility by 2-9

Tags: python

I have to generate a list of random numbers between 100 and 999, then write separate functions to check each number for divisibility by all numbers 2-9.

Later I want to create a dictionary from the generated list for each number tested for divisibility.  I will be using the random number as the key and using either yes or no for the value.

I know how to check divisibility for 1 number but having trouble with the rest, this is what I have so far

```
import random

#Creates the list of 100 random unique numbers
randNum = random.sample(range(100, 999), 100)
my_list = [randNum]
#prints that list
print(randNum)
```

Comment: We're here to help you with *your* code. What function have you written to check for divisibility?

Answer (score 1):

An expression such as

```
{n: [d for d in range(2,10) if n%d==0] for n in randNum}
```

would give you a dictionary where the key `n` is each of the numbers in `randNum` and the value is a list of divisors of `n` in the range 2..9

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a function that iterates through your random samples and checks divisibility for each number in the range you've provided. This function returns a list of tuples that can easily be converted to a dictionary.

```
import random

random.seed(8675309)

numbers = random.sample(range(100,999), 5)
divisible_by = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def check_divisibility(numbers=numbers, divisible_by=divisible_by):
    nums_and_divisors = []
    for i in numbers:
        divisors = []
        for j in divisible_by:
            if i % j == 0:
                divisors.append(j)
        nums_and_divisors.append((i, divisors))

    return nums_and_divisors

answer = check_divisibility(numbers=numbers, divisible_by=divisible_by)

# print(answer)
# [(511, [7]), (319, []), (622, [2]), (779, []), (616, [2, 4, 7, 8])]

dictionary = {key: value for key, value in answer}

# print(dictionary)
# {511: [7], 319: [], 622: [2], 779: [], 616: [2, 4, 7, 8]}
```